# Bootstrap datetimepicker only month and year not working as intended

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

My Datetime picker works on the fist click, but if I click again in the input field again it shows the picker with the day field. How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated.

This is the image in first click (expected behavior)

[image]

This is the image in second click (expected behavior is to come like to the first one)

[image]

My code is below

### HTML

```
<div class='input-group' id='dpRM'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control form-control-1 form-input input-sm fromq" placeholder="Enter Month and year" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#dpRM').datetimepicker({
            format: "MMMM YYYY",
            viewMode: "years",
            //minViewMode: 0,
            toolbarPlacement: "top",
            allowInputToggle: true,
            icons: {
                time: 'fa fa-time',
                date: 'fa fa-calendar',
                up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
                down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
                previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
                next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
                today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
                clear: 'fa fa-trash',
                close: 'fa fa-remove'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1850) affecting version `4.17.42` and `4.17.43`. You can modify datetimepicker code as suggested on github or use older version of the component like `4.17.37`.

Comment: Thanks , That was a quick help but unfortunately it dint work for me, i am trying though

Comment: commenting out currentViewMode = 0; worked for me in version 4.17.45

Answer (score 10):

Try as follow

```
$('#dpRM').datetimepicker({
    viewMode : 'months',
    format : 'MM/YYYY',
    toolbarPlacement: "top",
    allowInputToggle: true,
    icons: {
        time: 'fa fa-time',
        date: 'fa fa-calendar',
        up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
        down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
        today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-remove'
    }
});

$("#dpRM").on("dp.show", function(e) {
   $(e.target).data("DateTimePicker").viewMode("months"); 
});
```

REF :: [GitHub](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1894)

Comment: Just the event on dp.show works perfectly.  Thank you

Comment: You should accept the answer, better reference for others.

Comment: What do you mean by accepting the answer?

Comment: If my answer is solved your problem, you should tick green check beside my answer. An so, the others will take that answer as actual solution and this question need no more amswer. Do you got it?

Comment: Also you will see that my answer has 10 votes for solving other people problem.

Comment: Yep, already did that long time ago.  Great answer, thank you!

Comment: No bro, if you accept, green tick will shown under votes of my answer.

Comment: Sorry dude I don't see any green check beside your answer other than an UP and DOWN arrow for voting.  Did I miss something?  Can you provide a screenshot?