# Bootstrap DateTimePicker: Using Month/Year reverts back to showing days after clicked initially

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker v4.17.43 in MVC 4.5 project.  I set it up as follows:

```
    $(function() {
        var decDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31);
        $("#MyDatePicker")
            .datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'MM/YYYY',
                defaultDate: decDate
            });
    });
```

This initially works as expected, showing only the years.  However when clicking a second time, it reverts to show days.  I uninstalled all my jquery and bootstrap and reinstalled it from scratch making sure I got the latest stable versions (using Nuget Install) (jquery v3.1.1, bootstrap v3.3.7, bootstrap-datetimepicker v4.17.43).  Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Where your all code ?
you must need to show html & css or make a Sniper or Jsfiddle. [check it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1850) affecting version `4.17.42` and `4.17.43`. You can modify datetimepicker code as suggested on github or use older version of the component like `4.17.37`. The same problem was described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40396433/4131048)